# Unable to play large m4a audio file using wavesurfer

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to develop a UI for editing a audio file using wavesurfer.js.
I am adding this as feature to the existing ember application.
On loading large audio files of m4a format, I received an error:
error-handler.js:63 Error decoding audiobuffer
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv0lW.png)

Its working very well in firefox and its working in chrome(if i use plain javascript).
And its working in both browsers when tested with a new ember application.
Its only a problem with the current ember application and that too only in chrome.

Error decoding audio buffer
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Answer (score 0):

Ola @premji012, thanks for your question

This is unlikely an error specific to Ember as it is Just Javascript™️ and it should be able to run any external JavaScript library without any issue.

What it seems like to me is that you have an unhandled error in a promise somewhere that may or may not be related to using wavesurfer.js

When you open Chrome Devtools does it give you a stack-trace with a line number or more information about the unhandled error?